# Stray Python processes in memory on MacOS 11.6

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, conda

I have a Macbook Air M1 from 2020 with MacOS Big Sur (11.6). I regularly use Python with Jupyter notebooks, or from the terminal. To install Python, I use Anaconda3 for MacOS Apple Silicon. I often use Python from different `conda` environments.

After I close all windows and running python processes, and quit every application, the Activity Monitor application says that I have numerous Python processes in memory. These processes do not take any CPU, only just 10s Mb of memory. I occasionally quit the processes with activity monitor, but then they slowly build up again over time.

Why are these processes here? What can I do to prevent them from building up and taking memory? Is this a bug?

[image: stray processes]

Comment: These could be regular system processes written in python. I don't use Mac so don't know the tool, but can you get the full command line for these processes? That should tell you the script that is running and give you a good idea what is going on.

Comment: Try to find parent process of those processes with `ps -ef|grep python`

Comment: I recently quit all the stray processes. So I need to wait a moment to try that command.

Comment: In Activity Monitor, setting **View > All Process, Hierarchically** should give you the process tree. Not an Anaconda user, but I've never seen this with my Mambaforge installation on M1. Probably something specific to a package or the code in your notebooks.

Comment: @Philippe Here is the result of the command

```python
  501 60113     1   0  1:24PM ??         0:00.30 /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python /Users/nicholas/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.isort-2022.8.0/bundled/tool/server.py
```

Comment: So it looks like the processes have to do with an extension of VS Code.

Comment: Indeed, google search `"python.isort" "visual studio code" macos` might lead to some clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a bug in some versions of the `isort` extension to Visual Studio Code.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-isort/issues/241#issuecomment-1430587251

The problem is resolved with version `2023.9.10451716` (the pre-release version as of the date of this post)